# Cambiar el resultado cuando se introduzcan dos valores iguales a una misma variable en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una variable $descripción en la que se almacena el nombre del producto que se carga. Lo que quiero es que cuando a esta variable se le ingrese un nombre de producto que ya existe sume las cantidades de ambos el nuevo y el que ya esta ingresado. Tengo el siguiente código pero no me devuelve ningún valor.

```
            include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['codigo'])){
    $codigo=intval($_GET['codigo']);


    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from comprobante where codigo='".$codigo."'"); 




    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count==0){
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM comprobante WHERE codigo='".$codigo."'")){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
        </div>
        <?php 
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    } else {
        if ($count==1){
        if ($delete2=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM comprobante WHERE codigo='".$codigo."'")); }
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong></strong> datos eliminados exitosamente 
        </div>
        <?php
    }



}



if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));

     $id_tipo =intval($_REQUEST['id_tipo']);


     $aColumns = array('numero_comprobante');  
     $sTable = "comprobante";
     $sWhere = "";


     $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';

    if ($id_tipo>0){
        $sWhere .=" and id_tipo='$id_tipo'";
    }




    $sWhere.=" order by codigo desc";
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);




    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './comprobantes.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);



    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){

        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="success">


                <th>Numero de comprobante</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Compra</th>
                <th>Venta</th>
                <th>Utilidad</th>

                <th class='text-right'>Acciones</th>

            </tr>
            <?php
            $orden_pago=$id_tipo==1;
            $factura_compra=$id_tipo==2;
            $factura_venta=$id_tipo==3;
            $sTable = "products, comprobante, historial";
           $sWhere = "WHERE products.id_tipo=comprobante.id_tipo and products.id_producto=historial.id_producto"; 





           $suma_compras=0;
           $suma_ventas=0;
           $suma_utilidad=0;
           $suma_stock=0;
           $stock_compra=0;
           $stock_venta=0;
           $compra=0;
           $venta=0;
           $utilidad=0;

            $nums=1;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $codigo=$row['codigo'];

                    $numero_comprobante=$row['numero_comprobante'];
                    $descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
                    $precio=number_format($row['precio'],2,'.','');

                    $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
                    $total=$row['total'];

                    $fecha= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['fecha']));
                    $id_tipo=$row['id_tipo'];
                    $id_categoria=$row['id_categoria'];
                    $id_proveedor=$row['id_proveedor'];


              $query_tipo=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tipo where id_tipo='".$id_tipo."'");


                         $fetch_tipo=mysqli_fetch_array($query_tipo);
                         $nombre=$fetch_tipo['nombre'];

                         $total=$precio*$cantidad; 
     $sql="INSERT INTO products (id_producto, codigo_producto, nombre_producto, date_added, precio_producto, stock, id_proveedor, id_categoria) VALUES ('$codigo', '$numero_comprobante','$descripcion','$fecha','$precio','$cantidad','$id_proveedor','$id_categoria')";
    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);            
                        if ($nombre==$factura_compra){
                         $query_compra=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where id_producto");                                                        
                         $fetch_compra=mysqli_fetch_array($query_compra);
                         $id_producto=$fetch_compra['id_producto'];
                         $id_categoria=$row['id_categoria'];
                         $id_proveedor=$row['id_proveedor'];
                         $query_stock=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where stock");
                         $fetch_stock=mysqli_fetch_array($query_stock);
                         $stock=$fetch_stock['stock'];
                         $venta=0;  
                         $compra=$precio*$cantidad; 

                         $utilidad=$total-$utilidad;


                        }



                        elseif ($nombre==$factura_venta) {
                         $query_compra=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where id_producto");                                                        
                         $fetch_compra=mysqli_fetch_array($query_compra);
                         $id_producto=$fetch_compra['id_producto'];

                         $query_stock=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where stock");
                         $fetch_stock=mysqli_fetch_array($query_stock);
                         $stock=$fetch_stock['stock'];
                            $compra=0; 
                            $venta=$precio*$cantidad;

                            $utilidad=$total + $utilidad;                           
                        }
                        else {
                        $query_venta=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where id_producto");                                                          
                         $fetch_venta=mysqli_fetch_array($query_venta);
                         $id_producto=$fetch_venta['id_producto'];

                         $query_stock=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where stock");
                         $fetch_stock=mysqli_fetch_array($query_stock);
                         $stock=$fetch_stock['stock'];


                        $utilidad= $compra - $venta;                            


                        }



                    if ($id_tipo==2) {
                         $venta=0;  
                         $compra=$precio*$cantidad; 



                    }
                    elseif ($id_tipo==3) {
                        $compra=0; 
                            $venta=$precio*$cantidad;


                    } 

                    else {
                        $orden_pago = $cantidad-$cantidad;


                    }

                    $cantidades=$cantidad;
                    $stock=$cantidades;
                    $suma_stock+=$stock;
                    $utilidad=$venta - $compra;
                    $suma_compras+=$compra;
                    $suma_ventas+=$venta;
                    $suma_utilidad+=$utilidad;

                ?>
                <tr>



                    <td ><?php echo $numero_comprobante; ?></td>
                    <td ><?php echo $descripcion; ?></td>
                    <td >$ <?php echo $precio; ?></td>


                    <td ><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
                    <td >$ <?php echo number_format($total,2);?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $fecha?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $nombre; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $stock; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo number_format ($compra,2); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo number_format ($venta,2); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo number_format ($utilidad,2); ?></td>




}
```

Gracias. `

Comment: Porque en vez de hacer eso, no usas un arreglo asociativo donde por cada producto vas asignando las cantidades, sumandolas a medida que vayan apareciendo los del mismo tipo????

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, un arreglo con esta estructura: **`$arrArticulos=array(array('descripcion'=>'Art. 1', 'tipo'=>2, 'cantidad'=>5),array('descripcion'=>'Art. 2', 'tipo'=>9, 'cantidad'=>3),);`**...  y ya sólo sería cuestión de darle mantenimiento.

Comment: Si lo que que quieres es ir añadiendo cantidades al producto que ya existe, que pinta el tipo_id en todo eso?????

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: que es eso ¿$descripcion==$descripcion? comparas una misma variable xddddd

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres sumar un valor al de una variable puedes usar la expresion += o -= .

**$cantidades += $cantidad** es lo mismo que **$cantidades = $cantidades + $cantidad**

Fíjate que en tu código "$cantidades=$cantidad+$cantidad;" sumas dos veces la $cantidad que recibes y luego le asignas ese valor a la variable $cantidades.

Por otro lado necesitarías dos variables distintas para almacenar cada descripción y luego compararlas. Si comparas una variable consigo misma siempre va a ser igual.

Puedes probar con este código:

```
if ($descripcion1==$descripcion2) {
 switch($id_tipo) {
    case 1:
        $cantidades = $cantidad;
        break;
    case 2:
        $cantidades += $cantidad;
        break;
    case 3:
        $cantidades -= $cantidad;
        break;
    default:
        $cantidades = $cantidad;
        break;
 }
}
else {
 $cantidades= $cantidad;
}
```

Comment: Hola Femi, gracias por tu respuesta. Con ese código realiza la suma pero cuando se da una de las condiciones, la del $id_tipo pero lo hace independientemente de si la descripción es igual o distinta. Como podría hacerlo solo cuando la descripción sea la misma??

Comment: Si lo que que quieres es ir añadiendo cantidades al producto que ya existe, que pinta el tipo_id en todo eso?????

Comment: Hola @adriancasanova . La verdad es que me pasa lo mismo que a Dariel, no acabo de entender que función cumple id_tipo en tu programa. ¿Lo que necesitas es que si hay una id_tipo se ejecuten operaciones (suma, resta, etc.) independientemente de si la descripción es igual o no?

Comment: Hola Femi. Necesitaria que si hay una id_tipo se ejecuten operaciones (suma, resta, etc) pero solo cuando la descripcion es la misma. Osea cuando se ingrese una descripcion que ya existe dependiendo de la id_tipo sume o reste. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @adriancasanova. Creo que el ejemplo que te he dado cumple la función que me estas comentando. En el ejemplo primero se comprueba si la descripción es igual, si es igual es cuando entramos al switch para ver que $id_tipo es y según el resultado realizar una operación u otra. Si las descripciones no fuese iguales nunca se llegaría a ejecutar el switch. ¿Si la descripción no coincide hay que hacer algún tipo de operación?

Comment: Si, el código ejecuta las operaciones pero no interpreta la igualdad entre las descripciones. Algo estoy haciendo mal cuando defino $descripcion1 y $descripcion2. Como tendría que definir esas variables?? Gracias.

Comment: Necesitaría ver más partes del código para poder decirte como asignar los valores correspondientes. Las variables $descripcion1 y $descripcion2 son para almacenar las descripciones de los dos productos que quieres comparar, aunque realmente sería mejor crear una ID que identificase el tipo de producto y usarla para compararlos.

Comment: Tengo una variable $codigo  que es equivalente al id del producto. Pero no se como vincularlo.

Comment: @adriancasanova Lo siento pero tendría que ver más código para poder orientarte.

Comment: Ok. Edite la publicación con el código completo de esa pagina. Disculpa por la des prolijidad del código.

Comment: Esta es solo una de las paginas, desde donde debería llamar a las otras. De hay viene en parte lo des prolijo del código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar almacenando las descripciones en una variable que sea un arreglo y luego compara si existe la descripción en el arreglo con la función `in_array`:

```
$descripciones = array("Hola", "Hola1", "Hola2", "Hola3");
if (in_array($descripcion, $descripciones)) {
    $cantidades += $cantidad;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas.Gracias por sus respuestas.Soy bastante nuevo en este tema de la programación (cometo demasiados errores xd). En relación a la variable $id_tipo representa si lo que se esta cargando es una factura de compra, una facturar de venta o una orden de pago. En relación a la variable asociativa encuentro el problema (seguramente por ignorancia XD) de que son como mil productos. Como podría hacer? Entiendo lo de Diaz de Villegas aunque no se como aplicarlo en tantos productos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolverlo. Lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
       ´$sql1= "select * from comprobante where 
        descripcion='".$descripcion."'";        
        $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
        $fila = mysqli_num_rows($query1);     

        if ($fila==1) {
            $cantidades=$cantidad;

        }   
        else {
        if ($id_tipo==3) {
            $cantidades-=$cantidad;
        }           
        if ($id_tipo==2)  {

            $cantidades+=$cantidad;

        }

        if ($id_tipo==1)  {
            $cantidades-=$cantidad;             
        } 
        }´
```

Espero que le pueda servir a alguien.